# Sharing valet sites on local network

Tags: laravel, nginx, configuration-files, laravel-valet, valet

According to the section "**Sharing Sites On Your Local Network**" on [laravel.com/docs/7.x/valet#sharing-sites](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/valet#sharing-sites)

*It states this:*

> If you wish to allow other devices on your local network to access the
> Valet sites on your machine via your machine's IP address (eg:
> 192.168.1.10/app-name.test), you will need to manually edit the appropriate Nginx configuration file for that site to remove the
> restriction on the listen directive by removing the the 127.0.0.1:
> prefix on the directive for ports 80 and 443.

I am now trying to understand how to add a nginx configuration file for a specific site. i.e, http://my-site.test/

> (**manually edit the appropriate Nginx configuration file for that site**)

Answer (score 0):

You can open your website from local network only with IP address, eg. http://192.168.1.10/my-site.test